# Arrow-theoretic proof that cohomology is a functor.

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\sf{A}$ be an abelian category and $\sf{C}(\sf{A})$ be its category of complexes. I want to prove that the $i$-th cohomology is an additive functor $\sf{C}(\sf{A})\to\sf{A}$. For that, let $\varphi^\bullet:M^\bullet\to N^\bullet$ be a morphism of complexes. By the universal property of kernels, we have an induced morphism

[image]

In order for the universal property of cokernels to induce a morphism $H^i(\varphi^\bullet):H^i(M^\bullet)\to H^i(N^\bullet)$ making the diagram

[image]

commute, we have to show that the morphism $I^{i-1}_{M^\bullet}\to K^i_{M^\bullet}\to K^i_{N^\bullet} \to H^i(N^\bullet)$ is zero. That would follow from the existence of an induced map $I^{i-1}_{M^\bullet}\to I^{i-1}_{N^\bullet}$, but I can't seem to figure out why this exists.

Also, I would love to know if there's a simpler way to construct the induced morphism $H^i(\varphi^\bullet):H^i(M^\bullet)\to H^i(N^\bullet)$ since my construction seems a little tough to work with.

Comment: The map you say exist: you should use the fact that the image is formally the kernel of the kernel of a map, so that a map of chains induces a map between images. In an easier way, you can see that for a morphism $f: A \to B$ the object $im f$ fits into $A \to im f \to B $ with the first epimorphism and the second monomorphism. If you have a map $f' : A' \to B'$ and a commutative square $A \to A', B \to B'$ the above property gives a map $im f \to im f'$

Comment: And yes, there is no easier way to do that if you want an arrow theoretic proof. But remember: this is no harder than the case of abelian groups $ H_k(X) := \{ x \in X_k : dx = 0\} / \{ dx: x \in X_{k-1}\}$ in which you can do things with elements and the differential acting on them. It's just that in general abelian categories you can't "pick elements", but the essence of what you are doing is the same. Just use the dictionary between abelian groups and general abelian categories ($ dx =0$ means taking kernels, modding out is a cokernel, the image is the cokernel of the kernel...).

Comment: @AndreaMarino, I tried to do your "easier" method and, while I understand that we can factor $f$ through its image, I don't understand where the induced morphism between the images comes from. Could you explain a little further?

Comment: I tried to answer but apparently I can't do diagrams. The short answer is: kernel is functorial, cokernel is functorial, so image = kernel of cokernel is functorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deepening what I said in comments, I will show that for a commutative rectangle

[image]

Where $f, f'$ are surjective (means zero cokernel, equivalent to being epimorphism) and $g, g'$ are injective (means zero kernel, equivalent to being monomorphism), there exist an arrow $h_3 : X \to X' $ making the two squares commutative. Indeed let $C, C'$ be the kernels of $f, f'$ with natural maps $i: C \to A, i': C' \to A'$. Note that they are also the kernels of $gf, g'f'$ since $g,g'$ are monomorphisms. Consider the map $h_0 : C \to C'$ induced by the commutative square and the kernel property.

The map $f' h_1 : A \to X' $ is such that $ f'h_1 i = f'i' h_0 = 0$, so that by the universal property of
$$0 \to C \to A \to X \to 0$$
being an exact sequence there exist a map $h_3 : X \to X'$ such that $ h_3 f = f' h_1 $.

To verify that the rightside square is commutative, aka $h_2 g = g' h_3$ , precompose with $f$, then use the fact that $f$ is epi to deduce that the identity must be true.

I have been deliberately pedant and formal, so that you can practice with general diagram chasing. I suggest you to verify the small things that I have left here and there: you will get a lot more confident!

Comment: I added the diagram for you. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

You have a commutative square $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}X @>f>> Y \\ 
@VVV @VVV \\
Z@>g>> W\end{CD}$$
From this you can extract a commutative diagram $$\begin{CD}X @>>> \mathrm{im}(f) @>>> Y \\ 
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
Z@>>> \mathrm{im}(g) @>>> W\end{CD}$$

by using the definition of the image either as the kernel of the cokernel, or as the cokernel of the kernel.

Let me do the first one  : you get an induced diagram $$\begin{CD}X @>f>> Y @>>> \mathrm{coker}(f) \\ 
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
Z@>g>> W @>>> \mathrm{coker}(g)\end{CD}$$ by universal property of the cokernel, and now it's clear that you also get a diagram $$\begin{CD}\mathrm{im}(f) @>>> Y @>>> \mathrm{coker}(f)\\ 
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
\mathrm{im}(g) @>>> W @>>> \mathrm{coker}(g)\end{CD}$$ by universal property of the kernel.

Moreover, by uniqueness in the universal property of the kernel, you also get a commutative diagram $$\begin{CD}X @>>> \mathrm{im}(f) \\ 
@VVV @VVV \\
Z@>>> \mathrm{im}(g)\end{CD}$$ and pasting them gives the one I claimed.

Since everything here is defined in terms of universal properties this obviously gets you all the functoriality properties you might want